# Can a python script delete files on its own?

Tags: python, os.path

**EDIT: I checked hidden files but only 1 appeared, still 3 missing** 
Hello in the beginning the script below work smoothly but after a couple of runs without errors my list **files** became smaller. Any chance I can restore these files?

```
from os import listdir
from os import path
from os.path import isfile, join

path = '/Users/myname/Desktop/photos'
x = 1

files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
files.sort(key=lambda fn: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, fn)))
for target_img in onlyfiles :
  os.rename(path + '/' + target_img, path + '/' + str(x) ) 
  x += 1 
print(files)
```

Comment: check your recycling bin and see if it is there.

Comment: My bin is empty.

Comment: `onlyfiles` is undefined in that code, so there must be other code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1):

A python script will do the things you told him to do.

My suggestion is: take a look at the script you included. Some things I have detected:

1. The variable **onlyfiles** is not declared (I'm assuming it is **files**?).
2. Include logs (or prints) after and before **os.rename()** so you can verify the "renaming" is not doing anything unexpected.